# How to sign user in using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a RSpec before filter to log a user in. I have a products controller. In order to view products, a user must be logged in. I added a login method to spec/support/utilities like so:

```
def login(user)
  post login_path, email: user.email, password: "password"
end
```

Then I called the method in a before filter in my spec/controllers/products test:

```
before :each do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login(user)
end
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
The action '/login' could not be found for ProductsController
```

I have a route for `/login` and my user authentication is simple - just like [Railscasts #250 Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch). What am I missing?

Comment: What does the route for `/login` look like?

Comment: `get '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'`

Comment: I switched it to `get login_path`, but I still get the same error:

`The action '/login' could not be found for KasesController`

Comment: I've not seen the `to:` syntax used outside of setting the root path. Can you humor me and try with the route definition of `get '/login': 'sessions#new', as: 'login'`? Also, you're mixing the 1.8 and 1.9 hash syntax in the original post...

Comment: ok, your most recent edit removed the 1.8/1.9 hash syntax mixup :p

Comment: Does the `SessionsController` `new` action handle both GET and POST requests? If so, the route should be defined with `match` instead of `get`. You can limit the HTTP actions allowed to hit the action with `via`, e.g. `match '/login': 'sessions#new', as: 'login', via: [:get, :post]`

Comment: Yes, it's handling GET and POST requests, but I don't think it's a route problem...rake routes recognizes all of the routes. I think the issue has to do with ProductsController not being able to recognize the session routes.

Comment: The products controller has no need to recognize the session routes. The router is not routing the path correctly, which either means the route is not actually correct, or something else in your code is causing routing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a controller spec, then the problem is that Routes are not available when unit testing controllers. The point is to test in isolation, which means no routes

Comment: So how would you simulate signing in a user to test a products controller? A product can only be created viewed, edited, etc. by a logged in user. Would you only do integration/request tests in this case?

Comment: In an integration test, you're before block will just go through the view and log in. For a controller test, I'm not 100% sure what to do for homebrew authentication. Devise has a helper method that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Login is calling the ProductsController, that does not have a login method. As other told you, I wouldn't call one controller when you are testing another. Therefore, I think you should login some other way. For example:

```
def login(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

Comment: I mean I would replace your login method in spec/support/utilities with this. I hope it works.